# How to check is there any embedded object exist in .doc files?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have done for .docx files as below but for .doc file it is throwing InvalidFormatException.

```
public boolean checkForEmbeddedObj(File wordFile){

   InputStream inStream = new FileInputStream(wordFile);
   XWPFDocument xwDoc = new XWPFDocument(inStream );
   return xwDoc.getAllEmbedds().isEmpty();
}
```

Any idea How can I do the same for .doc files ?

Answer (score 0):

DOCX and DOC file have different specs and they are implemented differently in Apache POI.

**DOCX files:**

- use poi-ooxml library and XWPFDocument class

**DOC files**

- use poi-scratchpad library and HWPFDocument class

**OLD Doc files**

- use poi-scratchpad library and HWPFOldDocument class

In order to extract embedded data from doc file, you can use `OLE2ExtractorFactory.getEmbededDocsTextExtractors` as following:

```
import org.apache.poi.extractor.OLE2ExtractorFactory;
import org.apache.poi.extractor.POITextExtractor;
import org.apache.poi.hwpf.HWPFDocument;
import org.apache.poi.hwpf.extractor.WordExtractor;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

    void hwpfExtractor(File wordFile) throws IOException {

        HWPFDocument doc = new HWPFDocument(new FileInputStream(wordFile));

        POITextExtractor[] embeddedExtractors = OLE2ExtractorFactory.getEmbededDocsTextExtractors(new WordExtractor(doc));

        for (POITextExtractor ext : embeddedExtractors) {

            //ext could be one of the instance of org.apache.poi.extractor.POITextExtractor
            if (ext instanceof XXX) {
                // do stuff

            }


        }
    }
```

See also:

- [How to read doc and docx file in java with POI api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17617173/how-to-read-doc-and-docx-file-in-java-with-poi-api)
- https://poi.apache.org/text-extraction.html

Comment: Thankyou for your answer. I couldn't find any methods to check for embedded objects in HWPFDocument  class. am I missing something here ?

Comment: I am using  poi 3.7 OLE2ExtractorFactory class is not available in this version. I have tried [link](https://poi.apache.org/text-extraction.html) this but getting **No supported documents found in OLE2 stream** error
I dont want to read embedded object , just need to detect embedded object in doc.

Comment: `POITextExtractor[] embeddedExtractors` just check the size of this to detect embedded objects.

Comment: When you say i'm getting XYZ error.. please provide the full stacktrace for that. Stacktrace tells everything needed to find out the cause and try solving the problem.